# to write php variable in html option tag

Tags: php, html

i want to write a php variable inside a html option tag, but my code is not working.

```
<html>

<body>
    <?php $host="localhost" ; 
    $mysql_db="db" ; 
    $mysql_u="root" ; 
    $mysql_p="" ; 
    mysql_connect( "$host", "$mysql_u", "$mysql_p"); 
    mysql_select_db( "$mysql_db"); 
    $sel="select * from site" ; 
    $val=mysql_query($sel);
    while($row=m ysql_fetch_array($val, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    { 
            $a=$row[ 'a'];
            <option value="$a" name="a">$a</option>
    } ?>
</body>

</html>
```

i saved this file in .html extn is it right?

Comment: use echo like, echo '<option value="'.$a.'" name="a">'.$a.'</option>';

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered several times in several sites. This site is not a debugging service.

Comment: Saved it as a html file?? 
I think you should start learning the basics first. There are a huge amount of examples to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should echo it:

```
echo '<option value="'.$a.'" name="a">'.$a.'</option>';
```

And concatenate your vars.

Also, **don't** use the mysql extension, either use the **mysqli** or **PDO** extensions and **prepared statements**. Here's why: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Don't forget the mysql deprecation and removal.

Comment: sorry i can't get the output i saved this file in .html extn is it right?

Comment: The file's extension must be `.php`, you have to setup an `http` server with php support.

Comment: Thanks now its working i changed my file extn as .php

Answer (score 0):

first print the `select`

```
echo '<select>';
......
......

 while($row=m ysql_fetch_array($val, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    { 
            $a=$row['a'];
            echo "<option value=".$a." name='a'>".$a."</option>";
    } ?>
....
...
echo '</select>';
```